# Python Selenium WebElement element - invalid syntax

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scroll to a particular element on a page but before I do that I'm trying to set myelement to be a WebElement object, heres the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser.get("http://www.agoda.com/the-coast-resort-koh-phangan/hotel/koh-phangan-th.html")
WebElement myelement = browser.findElement(By.id("next-page"));
```

But it comes back with the error:

```
WebElement myelement = browser.findElement(By.id("next-page"));
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing?

Update: Ok looks like I was trying to write Java! as the first reply has stated, but then my question kind of changes since my actual code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.agoda.com/the-coast-resort-koh-phangan/hotel/koh-phangan-th.html")

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='next-page']").click()

myelement = browser.find_element(By.id("next-page"));
((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='next-page']").click()
```

Which gives the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-22-bb983f3ceca8>", line 10
    ((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Probably writing Java again, but how should this be amended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python isn't Java. (WebElement element = ...;)

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for the python methods etc.

What you actually want is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.agoda.com/the-coast-resort-koh-phangan/hotel/koh-phangan-th.html")
myelement = browser.find_element_by_id("next-page")
```

Although you can use `By` in the above but `find_element_by_id` is a bit more readable imo.

Edit:

Likewise for the second bit

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

I haven't used the above in awhile, so it may actually be the following I don't recall atm:

```
browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

You can also scroll to an element like this:

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, %d)" % element.location['y'])
```

`Thread.sleep(500);` also isn't going to work, and you can remove the semicolons `;` after your lines, they're not necessarily "wrong" but they are redundant.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but Ive updated my question as what I thought was the problem was not.

Comment: Thank you so much!